# Retrieve data from db and display in view through Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

Here is what i want..
I want to display some data from the database and display in the view in the form of a table. (earlier i was using a gridview in aspx)

I want to use jquery ajax to call the function, get the data and display it on the view all without a page refresh.

I know how to get a string from a function and display it into a label or something. but how can i achieve this?

Comment: Use ajax to call a controller method that returns a partial view of your table and update the DOM.

Comment: I got it till partial view call, but what should I write in the success call to display that partial view? I mean how to update the DOM in this case?

Comment: `success: function(response) { $(someElement).html(response); }`

Answer (score 1):

there is very simple, yo need a REST or any other service in the server side to access to database if you are using .NET you can create a Webservice SOAP or REST to access to Database. Once that be done just call it with jQuery.ajax() function like:

```
$.ajax( "localhost:2277/todos/" )
.done(function(result) {
  result.forEach((item, index) => {
    $('.list').append('<div id="' + item.id + '">' + item.name + '</div>');
  });
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery `$ajax` (or `$get` shorthand) method lets you specify a success function, which will be called when the response from the controller returns.

Inside the success function, you can do whatever you like with the response: display it in the DOM, execute some other function, or even make another ajax request.

Here is an example of the general structure:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Home/YourUrl',
    success: function (response) {
        // do whatever you want with the response
    }
});
```

I demonstrate how you can use the response to display the values in the DOM in my blog post [Using JQuery AJAX GET with ASP.NET MVC JsonResult](http://www.ojdevelops.com/2013/04/using-jquery-ajax-get-with-aspnet-mvc.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i already knew till this part. The query I have is what to write inside the //do whatever you want code, if my controller returned a datatable (or something similar to datatable which has a lot of rows to insert in table) and display it in a table like a foreach type of something